# SharePoint 2013 SPServices custom list script

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, caml, spservices

*UPDATED: This script now works and is a great reference for pulling custom list data with SPServices.*

I have a modified script that is working great thanks to the [SharePoint Hillbilly](http://www.sharepointhillbilly.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=5) . One script is for a title and description for a slider with multiple slides. The other is a footer element that pulls a name and email address from a custom list.

- The script for the slider is being loaded within a content webpart on
  the homepage.
- The script for the footer is placed and is running in the masterpage
  footer exactly where it needs to be generated.
- SPServices (jQuery 10+)
- jQuery 10+

### Thanks!

**SCRIPT 1 FOR SLIDER TEXT AND DESCRIPTION**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.SPServices-2013.02a.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" scr="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    //this is where the script starts after the page is loaded
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        alert("code firing");
        GetSliderText();
    });

    function GetSliderText()
    {
        //The Web Service method we are calling, to read list items we use 'GetListItems'
        var method = "GetListItems";

        //The display name of the list we are reading data from
        var list = "SliderText";

        //You can see here that we are using the internal field names.

        var fieldsToRead =     "<ViewFields>" +
                                "<FieldRef Name='slide1title' />" +
                                "<FieldRef Name='slide1description' />" +
                                "<FieldRef Name='slide2title' />" +
                                "<FieldRef Name='slide2description' />" +
                            "</ViewFields>";

        //CAML query
        var query = "<Query>" +
                        "<Where>" +
                            "<Neq>" +
                                "<FieldRef Name='ID'/><Value Type='Number'>0</Value>" + 
                            "</Neq>" +
                        "</Where>" +
                        "<OrderBy>" + 
                            "<FieldRef Name='Title'/>" +
                        "</OrderBy>" +
                    "</Query>";

        //Here is our SPServices Call where we pass in the variables that we set above
        $().SPServices({
                operation: method,
                async: false,  //if you set this to true, you may get faster performance, but your order may not be accurate.
                listName: list,
                CAMLViewFields: fieldsToRead,
                  CAMLQuery: query,
                      //this basically means "do the following code when the call is complete"
                    completefunc: function (xData, Status) { 
                        //this code iterates through every row of data returned from the web service call
                        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() { 
                            //here is where we are reading the field values and putting them in JavaScript variables
                            //notice that when we read a field value there is an "ows_" in front of the internal field name.
                            //this is a SharePoint Web Service quirk that you need to keep in mind. 
                            //so to read a field it is ALWAYS $(this).attr("ows_<internal field name>");

                            //get the field
                            var slide1title = ($(this).attr("ows_slide1title"));

                            //get the field
                            var slide1description = ($(this).attr("ows_slide1description"));

                            //get the field
                            var slide2title = ($(this).attr("ows_slide2title"));

                            //get the field
                            var slide2description = ($(this).attr("ows_slide2description"));


                            //call a function to add the data from the row to a div on the screen
                            AddRowToSlide1(slide1title,slide1description);
                            AddRowToSlide2(slide2title,slide2description);
                        });                
                    }
        });

}


// This renders the fields.
// 
// 
function AddRowToSlide1(slide1title,slide1description)
{
    $("#slide1").append("<h1>" + slide1title +  
                                "</h1><p>" + slide1description + "</p>");

}
function AddRowToSlide2(slide2title,slide2description)
{
    $("#slide2").append("<h1>" + slide2title +  
                                "</h1><p>" + slide2description + "</p>");

}

</script>
<!-- div where our slide data will go -->
        <div id="slide1"></div>


        <hr />

        <div id="slide2"></div>
```

**SCRIPT 2 FOR THE FOOTER AREA THAT PULLS NAME AND EMAIL ADDRESS**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.SPServices-2013.02a.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function() { 

    GetSiteOwner();

});

function GetSiteOwner()
{
        //The Web Service method we are calling, to read list items we use 'GetListItems'
        var method = "GetListItems";

        //The display name of the list we are reading data from
        var list = "SiteOwner";


        //For whatever list you want to read from, be sure to specify the fields you want returned. 
        var fieldsToRead =     "<ViewFields>" +
                                "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" +
                                "<FieldRef Name='Email_x0020_Address' />" +
                            "</ViewFields>";

        //CAML query
        var query = "<Query>" +
                        "<Where>" +
                            "<Neq>" +
                                "<FieldRef Name='ID'/><Value Type='Number'>0</Value>" + 
                            "</Neq>" +
                        "</Where>" +
                        "<OrderBy>" + 
                            "<FieldRef Name='Title'/>" +
                        "</OrderBy>" +
                    "</Query>";

        //Here is our SPServices Call where we pass in the variables that we set above
        $().SPServices({
                operation: method,
                async: false,  //if you set this to true, you may get faster performance, but your order may not be accurate.
                listName: list,
                CAMLViewFields: fieldsToRead,
                  CAMLQuery: query,
                      //this basically means "do the following code when the call is complete"
                    completefunc: function (xData, Status) { 
                        //this code iterates through every row of data returned from the web service call
                        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() { 
                            //here is where we are reading the field values and putting them in JavaScript variables
                            //notice that when we read a field value there is an "ows_" in front of the internal field name.
                            //this is a SharePoint Web Service quirk that you need to keep in mind. 
                            //so to read a field it is ALWAYS $(this).attr("ows_<internal field name>");

                            //get the title field (Site Owner's Name)
                            var name = ($(this).attr("ows_Title"));

                            //get the email address field
                            var emailaddress = ($(this).attr("ows_Email_x0020_Address"));



                            //call a function to add the data from the row to a table on the screen
                            AddRowToTable(name,emailaddress);

                        });                
                    }
        });

}


// This renders the site owner title and email address.
// 
// 
function AddRowToTable(name,emailaddress)
{
    $("#siteOwner").append("<p>" + name +  
                                "</p><a href='mailto:" + emailaddress + "'>" + emailaddress + "</a>");

}

</script>
<!-- div where our site owner will go -->
        <div id="siteOwner"></div>
```

Comment: Come on guys and gals... anyone??

Comment: What site template are you using ? Have you tried adding the slider script on the home page instead and see if it works ?

Comment: It's actually being served up in a content web part. I just solved the problem. I had a dup function so it was rendering all list data in the same div. SOLVED! This script is legit.